# Left join with most recent records before a certain date

Tags: mysql, database, view, left-join

I want to select currently active record based on a date. What I need to do is to create a view so a 'select everything' subquery is not going to work.

but right now I can only select one column because it says

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I could duplicate the select for all the fields I want to get but its going to be performance extensive, plus I have a lot of columns on the history table.

For this simple example (link below), lets say that I need to get the phone number as well.. any idea how I should go about doing it? Thanks.

SQL Fiddler:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff7e/1

I think I got it! Seems to work but need more records to try.

SQL Fiddler:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff7e/3

Still not working... zzz...I added a few more test data turned out it didn't work!

SQL Fiddler:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/360c1/1

My bad. **IT IS WORKING!** I inserted two duplicate primary keys for the history. Thanks all!!!!

SQL Fiddler:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/274c5/1

Answer (score 0):

You can add another subquery to the `select` clause:

```
SELECT user.username, user.password,
       (SELECT uh.name FROM user_history uh WHERE uh.user_id = user.user_id AND effective_date <= '2013-04-18' ORDER BY effective_date DESC LIMIT 1), 
       (SELECT uh.phone_number FROM user_history uh WHERE uh.user_id = user.user_id AND effective_date <= '2013-04-18' ORDER BY effective_date DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM user
ORDER BY username;
```

Comment: I got another way that seems to work (see updated question), this way will cause too much performance impact. i have more than a dozen of columns.. Thanks for your help though.